# How to minimize this sparse quadratic function?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-forms

There is a problem when I'm reading a paper.

Equation:

$min_p|p-p^*|^2+\alpha |R(p)|^2 + \beta |D(p)-\delta|^2$,

where $p, p^*, R(p), D(p), \delta$ are all $M\times N$ matrices, and $p^*, R(), D(), \delta$ are known.

The paper just mentioned "which (this equation) represents a sparse quadratic in $p$". According to this sentence, I cannot figure out how to solve this equation. Any hints would be appreciated.

Here is the [paper](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/L0Smoothing.pdf). The equation is on Page 4, eq.6.

Comment: Have you tried asking the authors of the paper directly?

Comment: Yes, I have sent an email to the author, but he has graduated and I can only find his university email.

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic form is positive semidefinite, so minimizing it requires solving a system of sparse linear equations corresponding to the gradient.    The paper mentions that [TAUCS](http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/) was used for solving this.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me more information or references about "solving a system of sparse linear equations corresponding to the gradient"? Is this $D()$ needs to be applied to the regular structure (image pixel or 3D vertex)?